# Linq to EF Include sub List for List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Given the following method which returns a blogpost, its parent Blog object and the list of comments for that blog post; I am trying to determine if there is a way, within this method, to also return the list of comment replies for each comment within the list of comments.

Here are the classes

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("BlogPost")]
    //[Index("IX_BlogPostIndex", 1, IsClustered = false, IsUnique = false)]
    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }

    public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CommentPostTime { get; set; }

    public List<Reply> CommentReplies { get; set; }


    [Required]    
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }
}

 public class Reply
{
    [Key]
    public int ReplyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReplyText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UserProfile MemberProfile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Comment")]
    [Index("IX_CommentIndex", 1, IsClustered = false, IsUnique = false)]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
   [Required]
    public DateTime ReplyPostTime { get; set; }


}
```

And the method

```
public BlogPost GetBlogPostById(int blogPostId)
{
    return _db.BlogPosts.Where(e => e.BlogPostId == blogPostId)
                        .Include(e => e.Comments)
                        .Include(e => e.Blog)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I can iterate through the return object from this method and retrieve the replies but am sure there must be a way, using LINQ, to do it within this method so they are part of the returned object rather than run another method to do so.

Comment: Can you give more information on how comment reply is represented? Without seeing how the relations one cannot write a query for it.

Comment: Added the class definitions to the OP

Comment: I personally would use an ICollection in your Comment model instead of List as well as use the key word virtual in front of that and in front of Comment Comment for your Reply model

Comment: @Edward...Why ICollection vs. List in this scenario? And what does virtual keyword do for me here? I'm not a professional programmer so interested in why to use there here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "Replies" is a navigation property on Comments, you can add an Include like so with your existing query:

```
.Include("Comments.Replies")
```

This works the same way as the Includes you have, just easier to include nested navigation properties

Comment: @Alex...great stuff, I never knew you could write the include with a string that way.